# Parsing a TarArchiveEntry as a String (the content of the file)

Tags: java, parsing, tar

I'm extracting files from a tar archive. If the entry is a .yaml, I'd like to get the content as a String. How can I achieve this ?

```
try {

    TarArchiveInputStream myTarFile = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/bazinga.tar.gz"))));

    TarArchiveEntry entry = null;


    myTarFile.read();

    while ((entry = myTarFile.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {

        if (entry.getName().equals("bazinga.yaml")) {

            String yamlAsString = entry.toString(); // fixme 

            HashMap map = new Yaml().load(yamlAsString); // snakeyaml library
        }
    }

    myTarFile.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you looked at [getFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.html#getFile--)? It returns a File object, not a string, though

Comment: Update : I could pass the InputStream (myTarFile) directly into Yaml.load() which returns the map I need